# Does the determinant of a substitution matrix need to be $\pm 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, tiling

The substitutional rule for the Fibonacci sequence is $\sigma: L \rightarrow LS, S \rightarrow L$, is:
$$
\sigma : \left ( \begin{array}{c}
L \\
S\\
\end{array}  \right ) \rightarrow \underbrace{\left ( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right )}_{=\mathcal{S}} \left ( \begin{array}{c}
L \\
S\\
\end{array}  \right )  = \left ( \begin{array}{c}
LS \\
S\\
\end{array}  \right ), $$
and $\mathrm{det}\, \mathcal{S} = -1$.

The substitutional rule for the Octonacci (or Pell) sequence is $\sigma: L \rightarrow LLS, S\rightarrow L$, or:
\begin{equation}
\sigma : \left ( \begin{array}{c}
L \\
S\\
\end{array}  \right ) \rightarrow \underbrace{\left ( \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right )}_{=\mathcal{S}} \left ( \begin{array}{c}
L \\
S\\
\end{array}  \right )  = \left ( \begin{array}{c}
LLS \\
S\\
\end{array}  \right ). 
\end{equation}

with $\mathrm{det}\, \mathcal{S} = -1$.

The substitution rule for the Ammmann-Beenker tiling is:
$$
 \left ( \begin{array}{cc}
3 & 2 \\
4 & 3 
\end{array} \right ) $$

whose determinant is $1$.

**Do substitution matrices need to have determinant $\pm 1$?**

What is the physical meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for instance the Thue-Morse substitution $a \mapsto ab, b \mapsto ba$ has determinant $0$, and the period doubling substitution $a \mapsto ab, b \mapsto aa$ has determinant $-2$.

When a substitution matrix has determinant $\pm 1$, then we call the substitution *unimodular*. You can find plenty of literature on *unimodular Pisot substitutions* for instance, which is related to the long standing open question known as the *Pisot conjecture* or *Pisot substitution conjecture*.